# UNICODE fonts not displayed in pdf created using TFPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

I have crated a pdf file using TFPDF php library. I have added some Hindi Text to the pdf. Only that hindi text is not visible(its in white color) in pdf. I have tried changing color but still its not visible.

following is the code I used

```
<?php

// Optionally define the filesystem path to your system fonts
// otherwise tFPDF will use [path to tFPDF]/font/unifont/ directory
// define("_SYSTEM_TTFONTS", "C:/Windows/Fonts/");

require('tfpdf.php');

$pdf = new tFPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

// Add a Unicode font (uses UTF-8)
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVu','','DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf',true); 
$pdf->SetFont('DejaVu','',14);

// Load a UTF-8 string from a file and print it
$txt = file_get_contents('HelloWorld.txt');
$pdf->SetTextColor(153,0,153);
$pdf->Write(8,$txt);

// Select a standard font (uses windows-1252)
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',14);
$pdf->Ln(10);

$pdf->Output();
?>
```

HelloWorld.txt contains

```
English: Hello World
Greek: Γειά σου κόσμος
Polish: Witaj świecie
Portuguese: Olá mundo
Russian: Здравствулте мир
Vietnamese: Xin chào thế giới
वैशेषिक दर्शन में मन विषयक विश्लेषण
```

output is

[image]

if I select the text then only hindi is visible

[image]